# html drag and drop css zoom

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with my drag and drog. Put simply I have an interface with tiles (div with tile inside) that are drag and drop. It works well only, I added a zoom option (CSS attribute) => betwen 0.5 and 1.5. Because of the zoom, the drag and drop kick does not work any more

So I changed my code and now it works

```
    var canvasHeight  = $('body').height();
    var canvasWidth   = $('body').width();

    var e = this.$el.draggable( {
      onDragStart: function(el){ self.onDragStart( el ); }
      ,onDragStop: function(el){ self.onDragStop( el ); }
      ,onDragMove: function(el, offset,x , y){ 
        var zoom = $('#view').css('zoom') || 1;
        x = Math.round(x / zoom);
        y = Math.round(y / zoom);
        self.onDragMove( el, offset, x, y ); 
      }
    } );
```

It works, however when I move, tile image is not moving as fast as my cursor. Why and how to correct it? (Even if the drag and drop works.)

You can change the speed of the image relative to the zoom?

I have the same effect it:
http://codepen.io/MAW/pen/zxQyxq

Thank you.

Comment: You're codepan example works OK for me, at the right speed for any zoom. Must be something with your device. Which one are you testing on?

Comment: Firefox, but it is true that I have no problem on Chrome.
You have no gap between the cursor and the image of the element draggabe